# How to keep a bone in-between other bones?

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

In my rig I would like to keep a bone in-between two other bones, so it is always in-between the two bones when rigging.

[image]

In the screenshot, the bone should always be between Bone 1 and Bone 2 when they are posed.
Is this possible? I tried looking through the different bone constraint, but can't figure out to use one or more of them to accomplish this result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need 4 constraints:

- Copy 100% Location from 1st bone
- Copy 50% Location from 2nd bone
- Copy 100% Rotation from 1st bone
- Copy 50% Rotation from 2nd bone

But if the reason for the middle bone is to fix the deformation, you should fix that in the weight painting. If the reason is to keep the volume of the middle part, then it is ok.

Comment: Thank you. This solution solves my problem. The reason was to keep the volume. I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of copy location constraint and stretch to constraint with a bone connected between the bone 1 and the bone 2. It's easier to explain with a blend file  :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the file. I can see how the constraints were used to accomplish this now.